# How to implement XACML policies?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, authorization, xacml, abac

I am working on a jsp hibernate project. Now i want to implement XACML policy in my project. Please guide me, how to build and implement XACML policies?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things

1. a means to edit XACML policies
2. a means to evaluate XACML policies i.e. you need a XACML decision engine also known as the Policy Decision Point (PDP). There are open-source and commercial engines available e.g.

   1. WSO2 Balana (OS)
   2. SunXACML (OS)
   3. Axiomatics (commercial)

With respect to editing policies you could simply use

1. JAXB against the XACML schema
2. ALFA Plugin for Eclipse
3. Another editor such as the one that comes with Oracle or Axiomatics.

Answer (score 0):

The basic components you require to implement XACML based design is to have:

- PDP (Policy Decision Point)
- PAP (Policy Administration point)
- PEP (Policy Enforcement Point)

where

**PDP** : PDP is actually the XACML engine which will do the policy evaluation and returns your application back the decision of the evaluation result either as "Allow" or "Deny" etc.(Independent component and nothing to implement inside your application)

**PAP** : This is actually for policy editor component where you will write and design the policies and can also save the policies to PDP. (Independent component and nothing to implement inside your application)

**PEP** : The component which actually communicates between your application and the XACML engine (i.e. PDP). Actually, it intercepts the requests coming to your application and sends it to PDP for getting the policy decision and based on that you can allow/disallow the content/access to the request. (This component is actually implemented inside your application)

Apart from it there is also an additional component called as **PIP** (Policy information point) which can be used for fetching the subject/user's attributes which are required for applicable policy in PDP and which are not passed from PEP to PDP

As David already provided you the available products and tools for implementing the same, you may make choice of having the same into your project or across different other projects/applications because except PEP all other components are independent of your application/project.